# can't run udev script when insert usb key

Tags: usb, script

I become mad, I don't understand why my script don't want to be launch by udev.
I have the latest raspian (wheezy)
My rule (in /etc/udev/rules.d/) :

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/udev/rules.d# cat 10-box.rules 
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/bin/test.sh"
```

Now my script :

```
root@raspberrypi:/usr/bin# ls -al test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27 Aug 22 11:06 test.sh

root@raspberrypi:/usr/bin# cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "YOU HAVE ADD A USB KEY"
```

The device (usb key) :

```
root@raspberrypi:/usr/bin# udevadm info -an /dev/sda1

..
looking at device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1':
KERNEL=="sda1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{ro}=="0"
ATTR{size}=="1031352"
ATTR{stat}=="     159        0     1280      180        0        0        0        0        0      180      180"
ATTR{partition}=="1"
ATTR{start}=="32"
ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"

looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda':
KERNELS=="sda"
SUBSYSTEMS=="block"
....
```

Why nothing append to stdout when I insert my key ???

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the script does not have a stdout.

Try this instead (where pi is the user who should be told)

```
#!/bin/sh
write pi <<EOM
YOU HAVE ADDED A USB KEY
EOM
```

Comment: It's not that it doesn't have a stdout, it's that it's not been redirected where you want it.  So you should be able to, e.g., `exec &> /dev/console` -- that's a bashism though (it redirects stdout and stderr), so use `#!/bin/bash`.   Beware that joan's version will `write` to user `pi`, mine only redirects to the system console, which you won't see in the GUI.